# Do Spring Data/Boot and JpaRepository provide patterns that tolerate a database being unavailable?

Tags: jpa, spring-data

Using Spring Boot 1.2.1 to build a web service that stores data in Postgres.

The service must "tolerate" the database being unavailable. By "tolerate" I mean the service will simply return 500 responses until the database is online again.

I defined a service:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired()
    private Repo repo;
    ...
```

Which uses a JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Execution, Long> ...
```

It works great if the database is up when the app starts. However, if the database isn't up then all the injection stuffs unrolls because apparently Hibernate can't figure out what dialect to use, which seems natural since it can't discover anything about the database:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
...
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
...
```

But the net result is a service that won't even start.

1. Do these frameworks have a pattern that addresses this use case?
2. Is my attempt to use DI with JpaRepository incompatible with an
   environment where external resources (the database) are not
   necessarily available?

Comment: Good question. Usually, when the DB goes down while the app server is running, you do get Internal Server Error and it can recover when the DB comes back. But errors during startup are often fatal.

Comment: I can get past the initial "Tomcat won't start" by just telling Hibernate what dialect to use, i.e., I added this to my application.properties: spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect . It may just be up to the developer (me) to make the rest of the service degrade gracefully.